# Writing _.Memoize from underbar in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently studying Javascript and am doing the underbar project(re-writing the _underbar library).

I have solved all of them but one, as I am stuck on _.memoize

This is my current code

```
_.memoize = function(func) {
    var cache = {};
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    return function() {
      var args = slice.call(arguments);
      if (args in cache) {
        return cache[args];
      } else {
        return (cache[args] = func.apply(this, args));
      }
    }
  };
```

This is the test case I am failing to pass

```
// Here, we wrap a dummy function in a spy. A spy is a wrapper function (much like _.memoize
// or _.once) that keeps track of interesting information about the function it's spying on;
// e.g. whether or not the function has been called.

it('should run the memoized function twice when given an array and then given a list of arguments', function() {
        // Be careful how you are checking if a set of arguments has been passed in already
        var spy = sinon.spy(function() { return 'Dummy output'; });
        var memoSpy = _.memoize(spy);

        memoSpy([1, 2, 3]);
        expect(spy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
        memoSpy(1, 2, 3);
        expect(spy).to.have.been.calledTwice;
      });
```

Or in words ' It should run the memoized function twice when given an array and then given a list of arguments'

I tried to change the args by checking if the first was a array and if not making all the arguments an array, but to no luck. I also tried to re write the code to hold a result and use Fibonacci to store the cache but it would run the function twice.

How would I resolve this test case?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: `memoSpy("1,2,3");`. What exactly does `args in cache` do?

Comment: other hint: `arguments` is already an array.

Answer (score 1):

Using `cache[args]` doesn't make much sense because `args` is an array, and using bracket notation will convert it to a string. You could make an array of arguments arrays to their return values, then compare the arrays:

```js
const _ = {};
_.memoize = function(func) {
  const allArgs = [];
  return function(...args) {
    // Try to find matching arguments in allArgs
    const result = allArgs.find(
      item => item.args.length === args.length && item.args.every(
        (arg, i) => args[i] === arg
      )
    );
    // If a matching argument array was found, return the result:
    if (result) return result.returnValue;
    const returnValue = func.apply(this, args);
    allArgs.push({ args, returnValue });
    return returnValue;
  }
};

const memoizedSum = _.memoize((...args) => {
  console.log('called with', args);
  return args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
});

console.log(memoizedSum(1, 2, 3));
console.log(memoizedSum(1, 2, 3));
console.log(memoizedSum(4, 5, 6));
```

Another option with less computational complexity would be to create a Map for each argument. For example, a call with arguments of `1, 2, 3` could result in a data structure of:

```
Map([[
  1, { nested: Map([[
    2, { nested: Map([[
      3, { result: 6 }
    ]])}
  ]])}
]])
```

Then you'd find whether a nested result exists for the given arguments by recursively iterating through the Maps with `.get` for each argument, instead of iterating through all arguments the function has been called with so far. The code would be complicated, but it'd be more efficient.

Comment: I guess the exercise is aiming for a simple `JSON.stringifiy`

Comment: If the arguments are guaranteed to all always be serializable, sure, but OP didn't say that and it doesn't seem like a safe assumption to make - it wouldn't faithfully implement `_.memoize`. Underscore's version does accept and properly cache non-serializable arguments

Answer (score 0):

Your function looks good, just one little detail. In your last return you should cache it first and then return it:

```js
cache[args] = func.apply(this, args);

return cache[args];
```